# EC2 port 8080 not open even added Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to test a simple http server on ec2 with port 8080 by `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` but it is not working. I have added the security group for TCP 8080, tried ALL TCP and even all All traffic. But still I cannot open the **Public_DNS_IPv4:8080** in the browser. I checked on the ec2 is listening to 8080 as per `netstat` below.
My ec2 AMI ID is *amzn-ami-hvm-2017.09.1.20180115-x86_64-gp2 (ami-97785bed)*

Interestingly, if I ran `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` then it is working on **Public_DNS_IPv4**

Can any one help to see what I have missed?

[image]

```
[ec2-user@XXXXXXX ~]$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...


[ec2-user@XXXXXXX ~]$ netstat -tulpn  | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8844/python
```

UPDATED Network ACL

[image]
[image]

route table
[image]

Comment: Do you have any network ACLs or iptables rules on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Post your route table and NACL (inbound and outbound). The reason that you had to use sudo for port 80 is that all ports below 1024 require privilege to open.

Comment: @JohnHanley thx, I have posted the Network ACL. think it is ok?

Comment: Your NACLs and Route Table are correct. I don't know what is wrong. Did you configure anything else on this instance such as iptables?

Comment: i didn't, I created a new instance and only touched security group to all traffic.

Answer (score 2):

it turns out to be my network firewall setup causing the issue, only certain ports are open.

Comment: where do we validate this in AWS?